# Matching Unicode Character in Python 2 and Python 3

Tags: python, python-2.7

Python 3

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> REGEX_KHMER = re.compile(r"[\u1780-\u17dd\u17e0-\u17e9\u17f0-\u17f9]+")
>>> value = "ហួយ"
>>> 
>>> re.search(REGEX_KHMER, value)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 3), match='ហួយ'>
```

But in Python 2

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> REGEX_KHMER = re.compile(r"[\u1780-\u17dd\u17e0-\u17e9\u17f0-\u17f9]+")
>>> 
>>> value = "ហួយ"
>>> 
>>> re.search(REGEX_KHMER, value)
>>> reg = re.search(REGEX_KHMER, value)
>>> reg
>>>
```

I desire the Python 3 behavior but why does the regex pattern fail to match Unicode character like `ហួយ` in Python 2 but is correctly working fine in Python 3?

Comment: I'm assuming you *must* use Python 2? Because in almost any circumstance, the best course of action here would be to move to Python 3, especially because working with non-English Unicode in Python 2 can be a real pain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I you truly *must* use Python 2, this should work there:

```
# coding=utf-8
import re

REGEX_KHMER = re.compile(ur"[\u1780-\u17dd\u17e0-\u17e9\u17f0-\u17f9]+", re.UNICODE)

value = ur"ហួយ"
match = re.search(REGEX_KHMER, value)
print(match.group(0))
```

So:

- be explicit about the encoding of the source file `coding=utf-8`
- prefix the strings with `ur` to indicate it's a utf-8 string
- tell the regex engine to expect Unicode